# redirecting std output and std error

Tags: io-redirection, stdout, stderr

I have been trying to figure out the relationship between file descriptors. One thing I don't understand is, how is:

```
ls -l /bin/usr > ls-output.txt 2>&1
```

different from:

```
ls -l /bin/usr 2>&1 >ls-output.txt
```

Comment: I know it doesnt work..what I am confused about is why..ultimately the stderr is pointing to the stdout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of the redirection is important as they are executed sequentially:

#### >filename 2>&1

`stdout` (`fd 1`) will point to `filename` and afterwards the `stderr` (`fd 2`) will point to the the target of `stdout` in this example `filename`.

That means that both `stdout` and `stderr` get redirected to `filename`

#### 2>&1 >filename

Here `stderr` (`fd 2`) will point to the target of `stdout` and afterwards `stdout` (`fd 1`) will redirect to `filename.`

This means that `stderr` will redirect to the original target of `stdout` and `stdout` gets redirected to `filename`.

So in short the order of redirects is important as each filedescriptor is independent of each other.

### Additional Information

For further information have a look at some other questions and answers such as:

- [File descriptors & shell scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13724/file-descriptors-shell-scripting)
- [What does "3>&1 1>&2 2>&3" do in a script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42728/what-does-31-12-23-do-in-a-script/42729#42729) etc.

Answer (score -2):

They're not.

a>&b redirects fd a to fd b.
if a is not given, 1 is assumed.
1 is stdout and 2 is stderr.

Some shells (e.g. Bash) also let you specify &> file to redirect both at the same time. However, > 2>&1 is more portable.

Comment: Aaron,thanks for the reply..I think they are different,the first outputs the stderr to the file but the second outputs the stderr to the stdout(screen)..But i dont get how this happens..both are ultimately pointing to stdout