# Redirection: what does this redirection chain do--logic and purpose?

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection, file-descriptors

recently came across several chained redirections to file descriptors as shown is the snippet below:

`name=$(dialog --inputbox "Please enter your phone number." 10 30 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 3>&1) || exit`

... while I understand this script is

1. Creating a new file-descriptor `3` which is is then redirecting to `STDOUT`,
2. Redirecting `STDOUT` to `STDERR`
3. `STDERR` to the file-descriptor `3`
4. Finally, redirecting file-descriptor `3` again to `STDOUT`

My question is why is this being done? It looks kind of circular to me, so it would be great if someone could explain the logic or possible purpose/use-case for wanting to chain the redirections this way.

TIA!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "3>&1 1>&2 2>&3" do in a script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42728/what-does-31-12-23-do-in-a-script) Regarding "why", I think you will need to ask who wrote the script.

Comment: @Quasímodo: I read that before posting. but thanks anyway.

Comment: Perhaps if you put the word "current" before each STDOUT and STDERR in your steps 1 to 4 it would make more sense to you?

Comment: The answer is the same as in Quasimodo’s suggestion above: it swaps stdout and stderr. The final `3>&1` doesn’t serve any purpose.

Comment: that's precisely what i was wondering. thanks @StephenKitt