# Piping in awk scripts

Tags: awk, io-redirection

I'm trying to write a `ls` wrapper that uses `awk` to parse the output of `ls -lhF`. Right now I've split the program into two files - `my_ls.sh` and `my_ls.awk`. `my_ls.sh`'s only purpose is to pipe the output of `ls -lhF` into `my_ls.awk`. It looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -lhF "$@" | my_ls.awk
```

I was wondering if there was any way to read the output of `ls -lhF` through the awk script itself.

**EDIT:** My main purpose is to write a script which shows the current directory contents in the form of a nice tree. A draft version of `my_ls.awk` would look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

( NF >= 9 ) {
    print "|-- [" $5 "] " $9
}
```

[This](https://i.minus.com/iSggaP2lAlT5W.png) is where I've reached so far.

Comment: [DON'T parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for your own good.  That is almost never the right approach for most tasks.  I would suggest telling us instead what you hope to accomplish, so others may suggest better approaches.

Comment: @jw013 That article warns about parsing `ls` in for loops etc. I don't see why I shouldn't use `awk` to parse it. AFAIK `ls` gives a clean output, with fields separated by whitespaces. And I think that `less` was created to parse exactly that kind of data.

Comment: I'd suggest re-reading the article, carefully this time.  The problem is `ls` doesn't display filenames reliably when strange characters are present.  There's also possible inconsistencies with the time format.  There is no reliable way to parse `ls` output - it doesn't matter what you try to use.  Awk does not have special magic that allows it to parse `ls`.  Finally, `less` is just a pager - it doesn't parse anything.

Comment: @jw013 Sure, but what I'm trying to implement is a `ls` wrapper. I have no intention of working with files based on the output of `ls`. I merely want to show the output in a different form. I still don't see how special characters would cause a problem to that. And I don't know why I mentioned `less` in my earlier comment (and I can't edit it now :P). I meant `awk` alright. https://github.com/trapd00r/ls--/ parses `ls` uses Perl.

Comment: If your end goal is simply cosmetic reformatting for display only, then most of the caveats don't apply - slightly garbled display in some cases is not a big deal.

Comment: @jw013 Yes, my goal is just reformatting the output. This is where I've reached so far - https://i.minus.com/iSggaP2lAlT5W.png

Comment: +1 for an attempt to solve your problem. Nice looking output. So you want to indent the child files in relation to their parent directories? That will be nice. To answer your question, you know about `ls -lfH ${@} | awk 'NR>9{print ....}'` don't you? You don't need an intervening script. 99% of all unix tools allow piping of stdout from 1st program, into stdin of 2nd program, and chained on to a reasonable infinity `stdout|stdin ...` Good luck.

Comment: Also, before you possibly reinvent an existing wheel, take a look at [`tree`](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/).  Most distributions have a package for it.

Comment: If you would still like to build your own, you might want to have a look at `stat` and build the desired output yourself, instead of tweaking the output of `ls`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll join the other advice that you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`, so this is a bad example. But as a more general matter, I would include the awk script directly in the shell script by passing it as an argument to `awk`.

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -lhF "$@" | awk '
    ( NF >= 9 ) {
        print "|-- [" $5 "] " $9
    }'
```

Note that if the awk script must include the `'` (single quote) character, you need to quote it: use `'\''` (close single quote, literal single quote, open single quote).

To avoid having to quote, you can use a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) instead. But it's awkward because you can't use standard input both to feed input to awk and to feed the script. You need to use an additional file descriptor (see [When would you use an additional file descriptor?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18899/when-would-you-use-an-additional-file-descriptor) [File descriptors & shell scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13724/file-descriptors-shell-scripting)).

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -lhF "$@" | awk -f /dev/fd/3 3<<'EOF'
( NF >= 9 ) {
    print "|-- [" $5 "] " $9
}
EOF
```

Inside awk, you can read input from another command using the `getline` function and the pipe construct. It's not the way awk is primarily designed to be used, but it can be made to work. You need to quote the file name arguments for the underlying shell, which is highly error-prone. And since the text to be processed doesn't come from the expected sources (standard input or the files named on the command line), you end up with all the code in the `BEGIN` block.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    command = "ls -lhF"
    for (i = 1; i <= ARGC; i++) {
        arg = ARGV[i];
        gsub("'", "'\\''", arg);
        command = command " '" arg "'";
    }
    ARGC = 0; for (i in ARGV) delete ARGV[i];
    while ((command | getline) > 0) {
        if (NF >= 9) { print "|-- [" $5 "] " $9 }
    }
}
```

In short, use a shell for what it's good at (such as piping commands together), and awk for what it's good at (such as text processing).

Comment: Note that instead of `'` you can use `\47`

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do, but one issue which can come up is getting `awk` to print out what `ls` considers to be the last field, but which `awk` does not consider to be so (via its default parsing). eg.

```
-rw-r--r-- | 433k | filename-with-no-spaces      
-rw-r--r-- |   1k | link containing  spaces -> /home/user/filename-with-no-spaces
```

Somehow you need to isolate the last `ls` field. The approach taken below, is to find the length of all preceding fields and delilimiter. The rest is the filename field (plus other info, like a link's target).

The script below determines the maximum width of the variable-width *size* field (needed for output formatting). There are multiple ways to get this width;   eg. *(1)* use `awk` to process each line of `ls`  output ,in the main loop, adding each line to an array for subequent `END{ }` processing.   or *(2)*  write the output of `ls` to a temporary file, and then have `awk` process that file.   The method shown below uses *(2)*.

*Note that the output of `ls` can send some perhaps unexpected, non-simple, outpt your way, as in the case of a `link`, so it is generally safer to use `find` and customize it's output to better suit your parsing needs.*

```
f=7               # the number of (multi-space) delimiters before the start of the filename  
myls="$(mktemp)"  # a temp file to hold  output from `ls`
w=$(ls --color=always -lFHk ~/ |tee "$myls" |awk '{print $5}' |wc -L) # max width of size field
h=k               # size unit
awk --re-interval -v"f=$f" -v"w=$w" -v"h=$h" '
  NF >= f {
    regex = "^([^ ]+ +){"f"}" 
    match( $0, regex )  # find start of name field
    printf( "%s | %"w"s%s | %s\n", $1, $5, h, substr( $0, RLENGTH ))
  }' "$myls"
rm "$myls"
```

Comment: Thanks! But still not what I asked. I wanted to know if I can get rid of all shell scripts, and process the output of `ls` using an awk script alone.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend avoiding reinventing the wheel, and instead using `tree`, which presents a directory's files/folders and subdirectories files/folders:

> tree(1) - Linux man page
>
> Name
>
> tree - list contents of directories in a tree-like format.
>
> Synopsis
>
> tree [-adfghilnopqrstuvxACDFNS] [-L level [-R]] [-H baseHREF] [-T
>   title] [-o filename] [--nolinks] [-P pattern] [-I pattern] [--inodes]
>   [--device] [--noreport] [--dirsfirst] [--version] [--help]
>   [--filelimit #] [directory ...]
>
> Description
>
> Tree is a recursive directory listing program that produces a depth
>   indented listing of files. Color is supported ala dircolors if the
>   LS_COLORS environment variable is set, output is to a tty, and the -C
>   flag is used. With no arguments, tree lists the files in the current
>   directory. When directory arguments are given, tree lists all the
>   files and/or directories found in the given directories each in turn.
>   Upon completion of listing all files/directories found, tree returns
>   the total number of files and/or directories listed.
>
> By default, when a symbolic link is encountered, the path that the
>   symbolic link refers to is printed after the name of the link in the
>   format:
>
> name -> real-path
>
> If the '-l' option is given and the symbolic link refers to an actual
>   directory, then tree will follow the path of the symbolic link as if
>   it were a real directory.