# Sending the output from 'dd' to awk/sed/grep

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, python, dd

I'm trying to approximate the computer's write speed using dd:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=1K count=10000
```

which gives the following output

```
10000+0 records in
10000+0 records out
10240000 bytes (10 MB) copied, 0.746313 s, 13.7 MB/s
```

How can I get the '13.7 MB/s' into a bash variable? I've tried piping the output from dd to progs like awk, sed and grep to no avail.

Ultimately, I'm calling this via `os.system(...)` from within a python script. If anyone knows of a more direct way to get a similar result inside python I'd be interested in that also. I'm trying to predict how long a file copy will take, based on the file size.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [File descriptors & shell scripting](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13724/file-descriptors-shell-scripting)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is your designated output from dd goes to `STDERR` and not `STDOUT` so you have to redirect `STDERR` as well and not only `STDOUT`.

For bash and zsh you can use `|&` instead of `|` which will also redirect `STDERR` to `STDIN` of the second command, e.g:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=1K count=10000 |& awk '/copied/ {print $8 " "  $9}'
```

The more general approach is to redirect STDERR explicitly with `2>&1`, e.g:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=1K count=10000 2>&1 | awk '/copied/ {print $8 " "  $9}'
```

For the python part have a look at at the subprocess module and [`Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) in particular.

Answer (score 2):

```
var=$(dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=1K count=10000 2>&1)
var=$(echo ${var##*,})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Bash [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) avoids the use of external commands, it is a good and elegant solution that 1_CR proposed.

However his proposition returns the wrong value (i.e. only the value behind the comma):

```
$ var=$(dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=1K count=10000 2>&1)
$ var=$(echo ${var##*,})
$ echo $var
8 MB/s # the wrong value
```

While the following right answer would give:

```
$ var=$(dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=1K count=10000 2>&1)
$ var=$(echo ${var##*s,})
$ echo $var
11,8 MB/s # the right value
```

Comment: That's because the decimal separator is the comma in your locale. By changing it to `s,`, you're moving the problem to locales where the word for seconds doesn't start with `s` (Russian, Japanese, Hungarian...).

Comment: Yes you are right! I didn't see that. Do you have a solution whatever the locale set?

Answer (score 1):

Another variation on the theme, getting all pertinent fields, avoiding external calls to awk or sed (uses read, which in bash is a built in)

```
IFS=' +' read in_full in_part _x _x \
out_full out_part _x _x \
bytes _x _x _x _x seconds _x speed speed_units < <(
  echo $(dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1024 count=7 2>&1) 
)

echo -e "$bytes bytes were read in $seconds seconds, speed was $speed $speed_units.\n$in_full full blocks, and $in_part partial blocks were read in.\n$out_full full blocks, and $out_part partial blocks were written out."
```

The same thing in one line (without \ line breaks)

```
IFS=' +' read in_full in_part _x _x out_full out_part _x _x bytes _x _x _x _x seconds _x speed speed_units < <( echo $(dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1024 count=7 2>&1) )
echo -e "$bytes bytes were read in $seconds seconds, speed was $speed $speed_units.\n$in_full full blocks, and $in_part partial blocks were read in.\n$out_full full blocks, and $out_part partial blocks were written out."
```

Comment: On CentOS 7, your example gives me: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Comment: @Pascal I was able to get it to work fine in CentOS 7. I also changed it up some to get rid of the weird escaping for the new lines by changing the redirected command to just be `<(dd ... |& xargs echo)` - the whole thing is still IMHO fragile and I wouldn't put it into production but it's a useful hack.