# Maximum time a file descriptor can be held

Tags: files

I am writing a long-running program in the Linux environment that will be calculating entries in a large table.  Every time it comes to the end of the row, it outputs the calculated values into a plaintext file.

To avoid having to continually reopen the file and append to it, I am considering just opening the file once and holding it open for the duration of the program.

I know that there is a limit on the maximum number of file descriptors that can be open at once, but is there a time limit on a single file descriptor being held for an extended period of time?

---

Note: The process I am running could potentially take a month or more to complete.

Comment: If there was such a limit, your system would crash when it's reached as all processes have open files, starting with the first one (`init`) without which the system cannot run.

Comment: Excellent point: I'll accept this answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for some solution as suggested over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462075/keep-a-file-open-forever-within-a-bash-script). So, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4412016/1742825) answer, I wanted to see if there is an option using `exec`. So, when I did a google search *linux append using file descriptor*, I got [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13726/47538) answer from user [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles).

So the essence of his answer is what I believe you are looking for.

```
exec 5>/tmp/foo       # open /tmp/foo for writing, on fd 5
while true; do        # 
  echo "Hello" >&5    # write to fd 5, i.e. /tmp/foo
done                  #
```

Regarding the maximum time the file descriptor can remain open, I believe as long as the loop terminates it will remain open as we are not closing the file descriptor here. You could find more information on that answer that I had linked to.

Comment: To clarify, I was speaking more of a limit in the kernel, not how to do this programmatically from the shell.

Comment: @mattingly890, I know. That's what I have specified in my last paragraph. It will remain open as long as we are not closing the file descriptor. If you check the answer I linked, it discusses it in detail.

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but none of the questions or answers you linked to were clear and unequivocal about the behavior of the Linux kernel in my specific situation.  I was not concerned about *how* to open a file indefinitely. I wanted a clear answer about whether the kernel had an internal time-to-live on open file descriptors.  It is a case of mechanics vs behavior.

Comment: @mattingly890, agreed. I am just a curious learner trying to explore new things always. Sorry that this one did not answer your query :)

Comment: Has anyone found out about the time limit, theoretically or at least by trying?